# Redirect to another in order to be able to connect to correct IP

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, rdp

In my office I don't have static IP address, therefore my external IP address changes often and that makes the RDP to my office computers painful. 
I was thinking of building an app that will live on one of the machines in the office and every 5 mins it will run to read the external IP address. If IP address is changes then it will save that to a database on the cloud. 
I also have another web site(noip.mysite.com) and that site will read the last external IP address from the database and redirects it to that IP address with necessary port.

For example:

I can put this info on my PC "1.1.1.1:3389" to connect to the machine on the office. How can I make that my web site also redirects me to that IP address with that port?

I tried the following already and it doesn't seem to work:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var url = Request.Url.ToString();
    Response.Redirect("1.1.1.1:3389");
}
```

So, basically what I want is to be able to type like this and get RDP access to the computer in the office:

[image]

Is there way to achieve what I am asking or not. If so, how can I do that?

Comment: "Redirect" is an HTTP concept (it's literally an HTTP header). Remote Desktop doesn't use HTTP; it uses RDP. I don't see how anything like this could possibly work.

Comment: You are most likely behind NAT, so the correct solution is to VPN into your work network, then use RDP into your hostname as usual.

Comment: Or use a product like TeamViewer or GoTo meeting, which are basically secure versions of the program you are trying to write.

Comment: @SSS My understanding was the same as yours until I saw this web site. https://www.noip.com/remote-access I was able to setup an account and it works fine. Is there some kind of magic that they do to make it work?